# RDP not opening a second time

Tags: rdp, internet-explorer

So I am testing a Citrix based vm farm that is publishing Windows 10 Enterprise desktops. Everything works with the exception of an RDP link on our intranet page.  All of our physical desktops can access the link fine day in and day out.  On the vm's you can use the link the first time, but never again.  This happens as a regular user and admin, first time you use the link rdp opens, you log in and off you go.  The next time IE tries to open the rdp file it does not recognize the rdp file as an rdp file but as _rdp, not .rdp.

Anyone have any ideas?  The .rdp file association is verified, if you open MSTSC and type in the name of the remote desktop the session connects, but not through the IE link.  Chrome works as well.  The intranet site is designed for IE 11, and all users use the link all day without issue.  The vm's are in the same OU as our other physical computers. Clearing the cache does not fix the issue.

Comment: I should add that the succesful attempts get prompted for a "open, save, cancel" banner for remote.rdp" and the failures get prompted for "open, save, cancel banner for remote_rdp" and the banner does not respond to clicks.

Comment: So from a physical machine you click a link that creates an RDP session to one of the Windows 10 virtual machines but from one of the Windows 10 virtual machines you click the link and it only works once. Why would you RDP to one of the Windows 10 virtual machines from one of the Windows 10 virtual machines? Or am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact the error come from Internet Explorer and the download got renamed, to _ in place of a dot(.) mean it's the protected mode that block you.

Internet Explorer in [protected mode](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwikxYy58sflAhVCnFkKHdwSD6oQFjADegQIDBAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F2864914%2Fenhanced-protected-mode-add-on-compatibility&usg=AOvVaw15-Q_GdNx31KeMboye1IVx) rename any file that can be dangerous, .exe, .pdf and as you can guess .rdp to _rdp, _pdf or _exe.

Open Internet Explorer on the Desktop

*Select "Tools"
Select "Internet Options"
Select "Security"
UNCHECK the box "Enable protected mode"
Click APPLY
Click OK*

[image]